# How to delete obsolete thumbnails in Windows 10's Start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, cache, thumbnails

If Windows 10's Start menu shows an obsolete thumbnail (i.e. you click it and see empty collections/albums/people/folders), why does it show thumbnails to images that were probably deleted a long time ago?

But more importantly, how can you get rid of it?

[image: Obsolete thumbnail]

Answer (score 1):

Based on @John's comment to the question, one can:

1. Right click the obsolete image
2. Disable Live Tile
3. Right click the obsolete image again
4. Enable Live Tile

The obsolete image is now finally gone.